# Validate file size and number of images uploaded

Tags: ruby, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to validate the size of an image uploaded with carrierwave and the amount of images uploaded by a user (preferably each images file size will be validated).

I am using nested_attributes in the following way

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :animal_images, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :animal_images, allow_destroy: :true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['image'].size > 2.megabytes }, limit: 3
end
```

So at the moment if an image is over 2MB if will fail silently and if a user tries to upload more than 3 images then I get a `NestedAttributes::TooManyRecords` exception, which doesn't look great from a user's point of view.

What I would like to do is include these validations in my current custom validation method so that I can add the errors to `[:base]`.

```
def dog_form_validation
  if name.blank?
    errors[:base] << "Please provide your Dog's name"
  end
  if age.blank?
    errors[:base] << "Please provide your Dog's age"
  end
 // More validations here
end
```

How can I access the animal_image array, 1) to check if it first exists and then 2) check its size? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

```
if animal_image[0].size > 2.megabytes
 errors[:base] << 'Please ensure file size is less than 2MB"
end
```

Comment: are you using `paperclip` or `carrierwave` for image upload??

Comment: carrierwave for image uploads, ill update my question

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use

```
memsize_of(animale_image[0]) > 2.megabytes
```

or

```
number_to_human_size(File.size("#{animal_image[0]}"))
```

To use `number_to_human_size` add `include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` to your class